# Using Intermediate Value Theorem to show that $f(x)=g(x)$ has a solution if $(f\circ f)(x)=(g\circ g)(x)$ has a solution and $f\circ g=g\circ f$

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f,g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be continuous functions such that $f\circ g=g\circ f$. Show that if $(f\circ f)(x)=(g\circ g)(x)$ has a solution, then $f(x)=g(x)$ also has a solution.

I feel that I need to use the Intermediate Value Theorem, as $f(x)=g(x)\implies f(x)-g(x)=0$. So basically I have to choose two $x$ with negative signs. But I failed to find such values of $x$, and I stuck here.

Comment: "So basically I have to choose two $x$ with negative signs" Why?

Comment: You could also sps. that $f=g$ has no solution, which means that, since f and g are continuous, f>g WLOG. Then you can easily construct a contradiction.

Comment: Sorry my mistake. I mean I want to find $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $(f-g)(a)<0<(f-g)(b)$, then by Bolzano’s Intermediate Value Theorem, there exists a point $c\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $(f-g)(c)=0$, i.e. $f(x)=g(x)$ has a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT**: Suppose $f(x)>g(x)$ for all $x$. Then $f(f(x))>g(f(x))$ for all $x$ and $f(g(x))>g(g(x))$ for all $x$.